# I have some confusions on pointer deletion and assigning pointer into class

Tags: c++, pointers

First of all, i had some confusion on pointer deletion. When i delete pointer a, i don't understand why int x is also deleted.. because i already assign a = f(which is the pointer pointing to y)

```
      int  x = 5;
      int  y = 3;

      int *a = &x;
      int *f = &y;

      a = f;

      delete a;

      cout << x; // Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Second, if i want to assign value to a class with a char * pointer. How can i do?

```
    class Foo{
    public:
    char * name;

    void setName(char * const newName){
           name = newName;
     }

    };



   void getInput()
   {
      char temp[5];
      Foo s;
      char * x = new char[5]; // four words
      cin >> temp;
      strcpy(x,temp);
      s.setName(x); // should i delete x pointer
                   // afterward because this function
                   // is going to terminated ?

   }
```

Comment: In C++ you don't delete pointers; you delete memory. `delete a` means to delete the memory block which `a` is pointing to.  (In some languages, you do really delete pointers, and the memory block is freed when there are no more pointers pointing to it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can only `delete` something that has been allocated with `new`. In your case, you are trying to delete something else, so you get undefined behaviour.
2. If you want your `Foo` class to "take ownership" of the pointer and be responsible for deleting it, then you should `delete name` in the class destructor.

Comment: is there any ways to delete int *a = &x; ?

Comment: @Shadow is there any reason you would *want to* ?

Comment: @Shadow no, and that question does not even make sense

Comment: @Shadow "free up" *what memory*? if it isn't `new`-ed, it isn't `delete`-ed. I'm not convinced you truly understand how pointers and dynamic memory in the C++ language are used. I think that would be a place to focus some study for awhile.

Comment: @Shadow the memory used to allocate both the pointed variable `x` and the pointer itself `a` is managed automatically, because they haven't been created with `new`. When they go out of scope (for example because the function is over) they will be deleted, and the memory assigned to them will be available to something else. The only thing you can do is setting `a = nullptr;` which ensures that `a` points to nothing and can't be dereferenced. But this doesn't affect memory allocation at all! The memory for automatic variables is freed when they go out of scope, no sooner and no later.

Answer (score 0):

Although a is a pointer, you can't delete it. It points to a memory block on the stack (not heap), it cannot be delete-ed.
The 'delete' operator is used to free up user-allocated space on the heap when you no longer have use of it. All allocated memory will be delete-ed once your application has ended automatically.

But... say you have a service that runs in the background in an endless loop and you allocate a space on the heap without delete it -> this allocated memory will most likely not be delete-ed (depends on the OS and type of pointer - volatile or not). It is in the developer's responsibility to make sure all allocated memory is delete-ed once his/her object is no longer in use (end of block or in the destructor).